# URL masking with MAGENTO

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any way of url masking with Magento.

For Eg :

Main website :

> www.magento.com

another domain :

> subdomain.magento.com

Now when i open www.magento.com website is masked/redirect to subdomain.magento.com with all the content of www.magento.com, and in URL it will display subdomain.magento.com.

let me know if this is possible in case of Magento without creating multiplestores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

1. Setup your URLs as “pointers” – all pointing to your Magento installation’s root directory
2. Navigate to your Magento Admin under System > Configuration > Web > Url Options and select “No” for “Auto-redirect to Base URL”.
3. That’s it! It should work exactly how you want it to.

Comment: This leads to double content problem in SEO. I would say.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: Yes, but can't it be resolved with canonical tag

Comment: Dexter to be honest I'm not sure whether the url in the tags is automatically filed with ONE url. Maybe it is different on both stores, but it doesn't matter :) I'm sure Deepak will make it work for him :)